# How to change reference to ItemsSource Ilist collection modify to ItemsSource collection generated from XMLDataProvider?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to modify a code where the content generated with ObservableCollection to collection generated with XMLDataprovider. I am able to generate the content with XMLDataProvider successfully. The problem I am trying to solve now is to modify the code where it is referenced to the content generated from ObservableCollection. Any time I run the method below, my application is getting frozen. It looks like IList is not appropriate reference to XML collection. What should be used instead? Thank you in advance.

```
public static void InsertItemInItemsControl(ItemsControl itemsControl, object itemToInsert, int insertionIndex)
    {
        if (itemToInsert != null)
        {
            IEnumerable itemsSource = itemsControl.ItemsSource;

            if (itemsSource == null)
            {
                itemsControl.Items.Insert(insertionIndex, itemToInsert);
            }
            // It looks like IList is not appropriate reference to XML collection           else if (itemsSource is IList)
            {
                ((IList)itemsSource).Insert(insertionIndex, itemToInsert);
            }
            else
            {
                Type type = itemsSource.GetType();
                Type genericIListType = type.GetInterface("IList`1");
                if (genericIListType != null)
                {
                    type.GetMethod("Insert").Invoke(itemsSource, new object[] { insertionIndex, itemToInsert });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?:

```
// it looks like IList is not appropriate reference to XML collection
else if (itemsSource is IList) 
{ 
    ((IList)itemsSource).Insert(insertionIndex, itemToInsert); 
}
```

Comment: The sample I have works with ObservableCollection, I need to genenerate content with XMLDataProvider. The method above is the portion of the code from drag and drop sample found here: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53. Please let me know if I answered to your question.